# Azure DevOps retention policy

Tags: azure-devops

There are 2 questions that was asked from my company manager and I haven´t found any specific information about that. I would like to know these 2 settings:

1. If there are any costs on extending those days in Azure DevOps projects
2. Is there a way to export that information

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> If there are any costs on extending those days in azure devops projects

No, there is no cost on extending those days.

> Is there a way to export that information

You could use Azure DevOps REST API - [`Result Retention Settings - Get`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/result-retention-settings/result-retention-settings-get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get the information.

Refer to the sample in postman as below, the `automatedResultsRetentionDuration` and `manualResultsRetentionDuration` is that you want.

[image]

Comment: Hi, if this reply is helpful, please consider [accepting it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), it can help other community members, thank you.